# the sample python twisted event driven web application increments request count by 2, why?

Tags: python, twisted

The sample code for a basic web server given by http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ seems to increment the request counter by two for each request, rather than by 1.

The code:

```
from twisted.web import server, resource
from twisted.internet import reactor

class HelloResource(resource.Resource):
    isLeaf = True
    numberRequests = 0

    def render_GET(self, request):
        self.numberRequests += 1
        request.setHeader("content-type", "text/plain")
        return "I am request #" + str(self.numberRequests) + "\n"

reactor.listenTCP(8080, server.Site(HelloResource()))
reactor.run()
```

Looking at the code, it looks like you should be able to connect to the url http://localhost:8080 and see:

```
I am request #1
```

Then refresh the page and see:

```
I am request #2
```

However, I see:

```
I am request #3
```

When I refresh again, I see:

```
I am request #5
```

So, judging from the counter, the server appears to call the function "render_GET" twice for each request.  I am running this on Windows 7 using Python 2.7.  Any idea what could be going on or is this expected behavior?

Update: The code is working perfectly, it's the browser that is being tricksy.  Each page refresh, the browser sends a GET request for "/" and "/favicon.ico", which accounts for the incrementing by 2, because the render_GET function actually is being called twice per page refresh.

Comment: Is this behavior consistent, or do the numbers change each time you try it?  Try holding down the F5 key in your browser to refresh really quickly, then check if the request numbers are always odd, or if it seems to skip numbers randomly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Browsers can behave in surprising ways.  If you try printing the full request, you might find it is requesting "/" and also "favicon.ico", for example.

Comment: That certainly explains the fact that there are two HTTP requests per "refresh" in the browser, but it shouldn't cause printing of only odd request numbers.

Comment: @AndréCaron: Why not? If it always requests the favicon after the page content, then it goes like (1) page, (2) icon, (3) page, (4) icon, etc, and all of the page numbers are going to be odd.

Comment: AFAICT, `render_GET` is called for all HTTP requests using the GET method, whether the URL is `/` or `/favicon.ico`.  Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Yup, adding the line to print the request showed that the browser is requesting "/" and "/favicon.ico" each page refresh.

Comment: @AndréCaron: Correct, but why do you think the answer does not address the cause of odd request numbers?

Comment: @icktoofay: unless I misunderstood something, the question implies that there are numbers missing in the output.  This would not be explained by your answer.  A race condition would explain that behavior.  However, it might just be that the problem description is misleading and numbers are not skipped but requests just come in pairs.

Comment: If I understand the code properly, you see the "request #3" message in the browser.  So it's only the requests for "/" that get displayed.  Add a print statement just before the return, and you'll see all the requests in the console.

Answer (score 2):

The browser might be making a second request for the `favicon.ico`.

You should have your server print the request location when it gets a request. This would tell you if this is correct.

Comment: That certainly explains the fact that there are two HTTP requests per "refresh" in the browser, but it shouldn't cause printing of only odd request numbers.