# KeyError even if key exists

Tags: python, twisted

I am running the following  code; it is from the Twisted Framework's example list and is of a webserver.

```
from twisted.web import server, resource
from twisted.internet import reactor

class HelloResource(resource.Resource):
    isLeaf = True
    numberRequests = 0

    def render_GET(self, request):
        self.numberRequests += 1
        request.setHeader("content-type", "text/plain")
        arg = request.args
        q = arg['q']

        #Added for debugging
        for key, value in arg.iteritems():
            print key, value

        return "I am request #" + str(self.numberRequests) + " " + q[0] + "\n"

reactor.listenTCP(8080, server.Site(HelloResource()))
reactor.run()
```

To execute:

```
[user@localhost pytwist]$ python twi.py
```

Browser URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/?q=test
```

However, I am getting the following [KeyError](http://wiki.python.org/moin/KeyError) Exception on the console:

```
File "twi.py", line 12, in render_GET
q = arg['q']
exceptions.KeyError: 'q'
```

Yet, the browser is giving expected output:

```
I am request #3 test
```

Also, the console is properly displaying the debug part of the code:

```
q ['af']
```

If the output is correct and the key exists properly, then what could be the error? Note that I have tried `dict.get()` method but the problem persists.

Comment: Did you try to print `request.args`, to see what is it's real content ?

Comment: @Y__ Yes, The output is appropriate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably because your browser is making two requests. The second request is probably for the `favicon.ico` file, and here it doesn't send the `q` parameter.

Try printing the URL requested.

**Related**

- [the sample python twisted event driven web application increments request count by 2, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253773/the-sample-python-twisted-event-driven-web-application-increments-request-count)

Comment: Seems to be the most likely of all case. But then how can I skip favicon.ico

Comment: @WeaklyTyped: Just return a 404.

Comment: Checked by doing a `print request.path`; the exception is indeed raised when */favicon.ico* is requested. I managed to skip it by doing a simple `if` check on `request.path`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I note something strange: your code mentions `q = arg['q']`, while the error message states `p = arg['q']` instead. Isn't there a mismatch here, or are you executing the good code ?